# Python Error: file.name.endswith() = a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which runs as a cronjob and is checking one specific directory if it's empty or not. If it's not empty I send a discord notification.

But I want to filter some file extensions and found a lot code examples in www but no one works for me.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check_motion.py", line 35, in <module>
    if file.is_file() and not file.name.lower().endswith(tuple(blacklistFileExt)):
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, datetime, argparse
from discord import webhook as dc


# motion directory for video files
motion_dir = "/home/pi/motion"

# Don't report files with these file extensions.
blacklistFileExt = ('.log', '.tmp')

# arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', "--config", required=True, help="config file")
args = parser.parse_args()


if os.path.isdir(motion_dir):
    if not os.listdir(motion_dir):
        print("directory is empty")
    else:
        print("directory is not empty")

        today = datetime.datetime.today()

        directory = os.fsencode(motion_dir)

        for file in os.scandir(directory):
            created_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))
            duration = today - created_date

            print(file)

            if file.is_file() and not file.name.lower().endswith(tuple(blacklistFileExt)):
                if (duration.days > 1):
                    # we have file(s) older than 1 day, so send Discord notification
                    dc.main(['-c', args.config, '-m', "There is a not uploaded file in motion.", '-k', __file__])
                    break

else:
    print("motion directory doesn't exist")
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's because the filename is represented with Bytes, so you need to use Bytes as well in the endswith method. Check https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes to see how to go from string to bytes

Comment: You could also use `blacklistFileExt = (b'.log', b'.tmp')` (with the `b` flags) to use bytes directly

Comment: @jkoestinger Wow. Thanks!!! Can't select your comment as correct answer. :-(